# Looking for in all performing functions in all rows of a tableview, instead of visible cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My question is clear,

I have a UITableView and UIMapView with annotations, when an annotation is tapped on the map, it will be found on the table and be selected since the user can recognize it.

But, if i try something it is only in visible cells, i am not able to do as i expected.

```
 - (void)annotationTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if ( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

    //NSLog(@"%@",[recognizer.view subviews]);

    UIImageView *temp = (UIImageView*)[recognizer.view viewWithTag:1000];

    UILabel *temp2 = (UILabel*)[temp viewWithTag:1001];

    NSArray *tapAndFind;


    if(isFiltered)
    {
        tapAndFind = filteredListContent;
    }
    else
    {
        tapAndFind = eczaneler;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<tapAndFind.count;i++)
    {

        Pharma *tempPharm = [tapAndFind objectAtIndex:i];

       if([tempPharm.CustomerIndex isEqualToString:temp2.text])
       {               
           EczaneCell *cell = (EczaneCell*)[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];




           for(EczaneCell * cell2 in [tableView1 visibleCells])
           {
               cell2.selected = NO;
           }


           cell.selected = YES;

           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableView1 indexPathForCell:cell].row
                                                       inSection:[tableView1 indexPathForCell:cell].section];

           [tableView1 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

           } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you plz provide your code..

Comment: i did, please check it

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `UITableView` is just a presentation of your data, not a data itself. So, when you tap on annotation, you should somehow find a correspondence with a data, the position of your annotation data in collection. Then you may calculate/find out the index of row in table, and then you can perform `UITableView`'s `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition`. Alternatively, you can mark the cell to make it distinguishable.

In your code

```
EczaneCell *cell = (EczaneCell*)[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

can return `nil` for `cell` when the cell for given index path is invisible. That's why you should check against data, not table cells.

Comment: if i use scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition, how can i find the scrollPosition to use it

Comment: `scrollPosition` is the member of `UITableViewScrollPosition` enumeration. You can choose the one that you need. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewScrollPosition

Comment: it does not solve my problem, i tried, i am taking mesh too large exception